# w3mのhtmlとソースの表示が一部のページで逆転する

Tags: browser

長年w3mを使ってきましたが、最近 **一部のページでhtmlとソースの表示が逆転**して困っております。

HTMLとして認識されていないのか、レイアウトが崩れ、文字が横並びになり、リンク表示もありません。
ソース表示にするとなぜか、HTMLのきれいなレイアウトになるのですが、当然リンクが効かないので不便です。

通常どおりに読ませてみても、

```
w3m https://weather.yahoo.co.jp/weather/jp/25/6010/25206.html
```

タイプを指定しても同じでした。

```
w3m -T text/html https://weather.yahoo.co.jp/weather/jp/25/6010/25206.html
```

[image: w3m https://weather.yahoo.co.jp/weather/jp/25/6010/25206.html]

これを <kbd>V</kbd> を押してソース表示にすると、通常のhtmlのように表示されますが、当然リンクは使えません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ただ以下は正常に表示されます。よってhtmlとして認識されていない疑いがあります。

```
curl https://weather.yahoo.co.jp/weather/jp/25/6010/25206.html | w3m -T text/html
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この問題はArch Linux系の**Manjaro Linuxのみで発生しています**。
**OS XやManjaroでもarmではこの症状は出ません。**

**zshの設定が関係している気がしますが**、原因を特定できません。
数ヶ月くらい前は問題なかったのですが…
(.zshrc大きくは変えてないですが、OS XとLinuxでは全く同じというわけにはゆきませんので。
またarmのほうは.zshrcの設定を減らしてます。)

対策を１月ほど探してましたが、だめでした。
もし何か良い対策やお気づきの点があればお教えください。

**症状がでるOS**
System:
Host: hoge Kernel: 5.17.9-1-MANJARO arch: x86_64 bits: 64 Console: pty pts/0
Distro: Manjaro Linux

**正常に表示されるOS**
System:
Host: hoge-pi Kernel: 5.15.48-1-MANJARO-ARM-RPI aarch64 bits: 64 Console: pty pts/0
Distro: Manjaro ARM

OSX 10.15.7

---

`w3m -v` で確認したバージョンはいずれもほぼ同じようです。

- intel:  This is w3m version w3m/0.5.3+git20220429
- arm  :This is w3m version w3m/0.5.3+git20220429
- OSX :This is w3m version w3m/0.5.3+git20200502

先程、興味深い現象が生じました。１回だけまともに表示されました。
cacheの問題(読み込むタイミング)なのでしょうか？

OSXでは　~/.w3m直下にbuffer(cacheのようなものか？)が存在しますが、他の２つは見つかりません。
~/.cahceや/var/cache にも見当たらない。何処に?

使用端末は、
OSX: iterm, alracritty
manjaro: xfce4-terminal , alracritty

OSXからsshでmanajroに入ってw3mを利用しても同じです。

.zshrcのご提案は後ほど試してみます。

---

問題のないarmの.zshrcを使うと正常に表示されます。
すると何が効いているのか？

正常に表示される場合、以下のアラートが出るので、これがあることで問題を引き起こしているのかもしれません。調査します。

$HOME/bin/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません。

上記の有無は関係ないようでした。

> w3m の表示が崩れている際に、C-l (画面再描画)や R (バッファ再読み込み) をすると変化するか

変わりません。

> echo $TERM の結果は何か

screen-256color

> w3m コマンドの直前に reset コマンドを実行すると変化するか

変化なし。

> w3m の表示が崩れている際に、! でコマンド入力プロンプトを出し、reset コマンドを実行すると変化するか

変化なし。

Comment: `.zshrc` が原因かもしれないという事でしたら、`.zshrc` を空にして（別ユーザーを用意してもいいですね）試してみてはいかがでしょうか。
また、関係あるか解らないのですが、使用している端末ソフトウェア（`xterm`、 `urxvt`, `gnome-terminal` など）も追記いただけると良いと思います。（情報の追加は、質問の編集で行なえます。回答として投稿する必要は無いです）

Comment: コメント追加すると見づらい上に、改行がうまくゆかないので諦めました。すいません。よって”回答”として回答させていただきます。

Comment: @yoda.55 コメントの追加では無く、質問の編集という操作が可能なので、それで追記をお願いします。

Comment: 改めてスクーンショットを見ると、`HTML` のソースが見えているというより、端末の制御に失敗している感じもしますね。追加で以下の情報の追記が可能でしたら、お願いします。〘`w3m` の表示が崩れている際に、`C-l` (画面再描画)や `R` (バッファ再読み込み) をすると変化するか〙〘 `echo $TERM` の結果は何か〙〘`w3m` コマンドの直前に `reset` コマンドを実行すると変化するか〙〘`w3m` の表示が崩れている際に、`!` でコマンド入力プロンプトを出し、`reset` コマンドを実行すると変化するか〙

Comment: 回答として投稿されていた内容を質問本文に転記しておきました。ご本人も一度質問も編集しているはずなので、追加情報は **質問の編集** を利用してください。

Comment: 「問題のないarmの `.zshrc` を使うと正常に表示されます」とのことですので、まずは `.zshrc` のどの記述が原因かの確定をお勧めします。空の `.zshrc` から始めて記述を足していく、あるいはその逆、などで簡単に確定できると思います。

Comment: cubickさん転記ありがとうございました。

Comment: これ以上進展もなさそうですので、manjaro本家で確認します。この質問を取り下げるにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

的を外していたら恐縮ですが、よく見ると以下のようなエラーが生じています。

```bash
$ w3m https://weather.yahoo.co.jp/weather/jp/25/6010/25206.html

append : to filename to view the html file Link: [1]canonical Link:
```

これを調べると、以下のような話が出てきます。この分野は私は全く素人なので、よくわかりませんが、yahooなどが**canonicalタグ**を採用した影響なのでしょうか？

https://www.comix.co.jp/blog/canonical/